# Disable choice list in Django admin, only for editing

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-1.8

I want to disable some fields when I am editing an object. I have managed to do this for text fields, but it's been impossible for a dropdown list (choice list).

I am doing this action in the constructor of the form.

```
class OrderModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            self.fields['description'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
            self.fields['city_code'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
```

Notice how I made it for both with different **keywords**, but I can't do it for my `customer_id` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the attribute to `disabled` or `readonly` only affects the way the widgets are displayed. It doesn't actually stop somebody submitting a post request that changes those fields.

It might be a better approach to override [`get_readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields) for your model.

```
class OrderModelAdmin(admin.Model
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if self.obj.pk:
            return ['description', 'city_code', 'customer']
        else:
            return []
```

Comment: Wow! Excellent solution. Thanks!

Comment: Quick, question, do you know why am I getting my readonly fields duplicated in the form?

Comment: I'm not sure what would cause the fields to be duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Alasdair is better than this one (because this one doesn't prevent a submission). But I post it, just in case someone wants the equivalent to 'readonly' for `ModelChoiceField`.

```
self.fields['customer_id'].widget.widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
```

Notice, that for a `ChoiceField` is enought something like this:

```
self.fields['city_code'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
```